# Characterization using YOSYS

Tags: delay, area, energy, yosys

Is there any way to obtain the Area, Energy Consumption or time delay of a mapped circuit using YOSYS?

This is my synthesis script:

```
read_verilog UBBKA_15_0_15_0.v
hierarchy -top UBBKA_15_0_15_0
prep; flatten; synth
clean -purge

dfflibmap -liberty NanGate15nm.lib
abc -liberty NanGate15nm.lib
clean -purge

write_verilog -noattr -noexpr netlits.v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stat` or `stat -lib` (with a liberty file) for area/gate usage information.

When given a delay target with `-D`, `abc` will print some delay information about the mapping (at a minimum, whether it was able to meet that target).

I am not aware of a way to do power analysis with Yosys at present.